# How to pass url using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to show a div when changing an input option using ajax, but it is not working. I think I put incorrect syntax but I don't know where.

here is my student.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('asign')}}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
   <p>Are you a student?</p>
   <select name="student" id="student">
      <option value="1">Yes, I am a student</option>
      <option value="0">No, I am a guest</option>
   </select>
   <div id="msg"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
   var url = '{{ route('student') }}';
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#student").change(function(){
         var student= $(this).val();
         var dataString = "student="+student;
         $.ajax({ 
           method: "POST", 
           url: url, 
           data: {dataString: dataString, _token : token}
           success: function(result){
               $("#msg").html(result.msg);
           }
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Then, here is my student file I put it in view/student/student.blade.php

```
@if($_POST['student'] == '1')
<input type="number" name="sNumber" placeholder="Enter your student number" 
class="input"> 
<br><br>
@else
Thank you for joining us.
@endif
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/student/student')->name('student');
```

I have put the jquery script link into my layout view so, it must not be the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a div on change of dropdown then why you are using ajax for this? You can use jQuery to achieve this like below.

```
<form action="{{ route('asign')}}" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <p>Are you a student?</p>
  <select name="student" id="student">
    <option value="1">Yes, I am a student</option>
    <option value="0">No, I am a guest</option>
  </select>
  <div id="msg" style="display:none;">Something to show on student value 1 only.</div> 
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#student").change(function(){
     var student= $(this).val();
     if(student == 1){
         $('#msg').show();
     }else{
         $('#msg').hide();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: it may work. But, I am trying to have the div in a separate file then I call it. This should do when I deal with larger code to simplification.

Comment: You can put this code `<div id="msg" style="display:none;">Something to show on student value 1 only.</div>` in your blade file and then include this blade like ` @include('student.student')` where first student will be your directory in the views and second student will be your blade like `student.blade.php`. No matter how much content you put in this blade. Only thing you need to care about is that all content must be in between this div. `<div id="msg" style="display:none;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I think it`s your ajax`s data param problem,if you use key:value format,then you shouldn`t use query string and key:value together.Change `data: {dataString: dataString, _token : token}` to `data: {student: student, _token : token}`, have a try.

And by the way.is your second code part in the same file with the first one?if so, I don`t think that will work fine.Because it`s different between server-side script(php code) and client script(js script).

Comment: nothing happen....
my second code part is in a different file as I have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

you can check your ajax code:

```
data: {dataString: dataString, _token : token},
```

lack ","